Windows 10 sc delete gives me DeleteService FAILED 1072 The specified service has been marked for deletion
I've tried both sc delete and pwsh's Remove-Service but the service is still there. Subsequent calls to sc delete (or Remove-Service) give me this 1072 error.
PS C:\>sc delete MyService
[SC] DeleteService FAILED 1072:

The specified service has been marked for deletion.

Was this fixed on Win11?
EDIT: Note: Normally, the service gets removed without problems. This happens every once in a while.

If the service is actually in use, when the manager asks it to shut down in preparation for deletion it will respond with "unable to shut down now, in use" and the manager will return this error to SC. This can happen if a process starts a session with the service but does not ever actually close that session - possibly because it crashed, possibly because it's still running in the background. The only way I've found to deal with this in any Windows variant is to reboot the system.

There's probably a pending reboot. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSSystemInfo/1.0/Content/Public%5CGet-PendingReboot.ps1

Forceful killing the process fixed the issue:
taskkill /pid (sc.exe queryex MyService | Select-String 'PID\s+:\s+(\d+)' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }) /f


I generally don't recommend force-killing services. Yes, it works, but it doesn't give them time to close out resources, and if they have files open, those files can get corrupted.
